# how to set a Drupal rules action to play a sound file

Tags: audio, drupal-7, drupal-rules

How can I set up a Drupal rules action to play a specific sound file.

Eg I thought I can do this with the action 'fetch an entity', the entity value as 'file' and the property value 'title' (thinking title would be the file name?) but then how can I enter the file name? The only options for the property value are data selectors, which do not include the file names.